# Preserve Content-Type when uploading a file from another URL without saving locally

Tags: curl, wget

Given many files (or one large file), I want to download from one server and upload to another without storing files locally.  Right now, I'm using:

`wget -q -O - <source> | curl --silent --show-error --fail -X PUT -d @- <destination>`

but this uploads the file with the default `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Is there a way to preserve the original Content-Type?

Answer (score 1):

With curl just set the header, for example,`-H 'Content-Type: text/html'`:

```
cat 1.html | curl --silent --show-error --fail -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/html' -d @- localhost:8000
```

and on the server you get:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

Usually (as with a browser), file upload requires a method=post and enctype="multipart/form-data".  Content-Type can then be set per part.  With curl you would do that with:

```
curl ... -F "file=@-;type=text/html" <destination>
```

and on the server you you would get:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------2fa1094be9afdaa6
...
--------------------------2fa1094be9afdaa6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="-"
Content-Type: text/html
...
```

You need to extract the relevant content type from the wget header.  Perhaps by using the --save-headers option?  First read the content into a variable `file`, extract the header field value into the variable `content_type`, then pass everything but header to curl which you can now call with $content_type per above:

```
wget ... | { file=$(</dev/stdin); content_type=$(echo "$file" | sed -n '1,/^\r$/ { /^Content-Type: /{ s/.*: \(.*\)/\1/p; q } }'); echo "$file" | sed '1,/^\r$/d' | curl ... }
```